# What answers will I get when asking this questions

Tags: prolog

I started to learn Prolog and want to solve this task. But I am not quite shure whether I am right or not. Pls, help me

[image: prologtask]

- `pilots(A,london) = pilots(london, paris)`
- `point(X,Y,Z)     = point(X1,Y1,Z1)`
- `letter(C)        = word(letter)`
- `noun(alpha)      = alpha`
- `'vicar'          = vicar`

I think that everything will give "no", but the last one will be yes. Z will be equal b, X=Z=b

Comment: I forgot to paste the last example where I am sure in result
f(X,a(b,c)) =f(Z,a(Z,c)
Z will be equal b, X=Z=b
Right?

Answer (score 2):

Just try them in prolog.

| Expression | Result | Explanation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `pilots(A,london) = pilots(london,paris)` | `false` | Variable `A` unifies with the atom `london`, but the atoms `london` and `paris` do not. |
| `point(X,Y,Z) = point(X1,Y1,Z1)` | `true` | The variable pairs `X` and `X1`, `Y` and `Y1`, and `Z` and `Z1` each unify and become the same variable. |
| `letter(C) = word(letter)` | `false` | Although `letter/1` and `word/1` have the same *arity*, they have different *functors* and so do not unify. |
| `noun(alpha) = alpha` | `false` | The structure/term `noun(alpha)` with functor `noun` and arity 1 (`noun/1`) cannot unify with the atom `alpha` |
| `'vicar' = vicar` | `true` | Text delimited by single quotes (e.g., `'vicar'`) denotes an atom; the *bare word* `vicar` likewise denotes an atom, and, in fact, the exact, **same** atom as `vicar`: they unify (because they are identical. |

Comment: Great! Thanks. And what about this two?1.  f(X,X) == f(a,b) 2. point(Х,У,Z) = point(Xl,Yl,Zl) = word(letter)